# Dart Map Sort - Based on Values which are Lists

Tags: dart

What would be the best way to sort a Map where keys are Strings and values are Lists of ints.

```
var userVotes = {
  "arbourn": [1, 0, 7],
  "burun": [2, 9, 0, 1],
  "niko": [1, 0, 3, 10],
};
```

The sorting is done on the basis of Lists (values). 
1. List with first value higher wins
2. In case of same values, List with bigger length wins.
3. Else, no change in map (not very important)
Expected output is

```
var userVotes = {
  "burun": [2, 9, 0, 1],
  "arbourn": [1, 0, 7],
  "niko": [1, 0, 3, 10],
};
```

Performance Criteria - The length of List is bounded to be <=100 and number of keys <=1000.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is "arbourn" second in your example if the rule 2 state: "In case of same values, List with bigger length wins"?

Comment: Becuase, the value for 'arbourn' is [1,0,7]. In this list '7' comes at 3rd pos while comparing to niko where 3rd pos is '3'. So this list wins

Comment: Ok, so we should compare the two lists until one of them have no more elements and in this case the longest list wins?

Comment: Yes, sounds just right!

Comment: Sorting a map by the values as somewhat antithetical to maps as a whole, particularly to `LinkedHashMap` (the default `Map` implementation in Dart) which is not designed to be sortable. There is `SplayTreeMap` which does sort its contents, but it sorts by the keys, not by the values. In this case, I would argue that it would be far more appropriate to instead have an ordered list of data objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could be done:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final userVotes = {
    "arbourn": [1, 0, 7],
    "burun": [2, 9, 0, 1],
    "niko": [1, 0, 3, 10],
    "niko2": [1, 0, 3, 10, 0],
  };

  final sortedMap =
      LinkedHashMap.fromEntries(userVotes.entries.toList()..sort(sortMethod));

  sortedMap.forEach((key, value) => print('$key: $value'));
}

int sortMethod(MapEntry<String, List<int>> e1, MapEntry<String, List<int>> e2) {
  final l1 = e1.value;
  final l2 = e2.value;
  final minLength = l1.length > l2.length ? l2.length : l1.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    if (l1[i] > l2[i]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (l1[i] < l2[i]) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return l2.length.compareTo(l1.length);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
burun: [2, 9, 0, 1]
arbourn: [1, 0, 7]
niko2: [1, 0, 3, 10, 0]
niko: [1, 0, 3, 10]
```

#### Edit

Since it is not really that great to sort maps, a better strategy would be to convert each key-value pair into a `UserVote` object which implements `compareTo` to other `UserVote` objects. This objects can be put into a list and sorted.

```
import 'dart:collection';

class UserVote implements Comparable<UserVote> {
  final String name;
  final List<int> list;

  const UserVote(this.name, this.list);

  @override
  int compareTo(UserVote o) {
    final minLength = list.length > o.list.length ? o.list.length : list.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
      if (list[i] > o.list[i]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (list[i] < o.list[i]) {
        return 1;
      }
    }

    return o.list.length.compareTo(list.length);
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '$name: $list';
}

void main() {
  final userVotes = {
    "arbourn": [1, 0, 7],
    "burun": [2, 9, 0, 1],
    "niko": [1, 0, 3, 10],
    "niko2": [1, 0, 3, 10, 0],
  };

  final listOfUserVotes =
      userVotes.entries.map((e) => UserVote(e.key, e.value)).toList();

  listOfUserVotes.sort();
  listOfUserVotes.forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: The fact that in order to have a "map sorted by values" the entries need to be converted to a list really just goes to show that a map is the wrong data structure to use for this operation.

Comment: I fully agree that Map (which are normally consider an unsorted data structure but LinkedHashMap will keep the order) is not really that great to represent this data. In general, I am a little concerned that I have seen multiple Dart questions here on SO about how to sort maps.

Comment: I mean, it is possible to have sorted maps in Dart with the `SplayTreeMap`, but that sorts on the keys rather than the values. Generally speaking, if you have to perform language-gymnastics to achieve certain functionality, then somewhere along the line you've done something wrong.

Comment: I have added an example of how to do it in another way by making a `UserVote` object with a `compareTo` method.

Comment: @Abion47 I don't get the argument of not using map when we need to sort by values. The use case of hashing objects by some keys and then getting the objects out based on some constraints one after another is very common. The only constraint I see is that object (key in this case) must be hashable and constant .

Comment: @Mahori Because after you've performed the sorting, you are depending on the result having a fixed ordering that has nothing to do with the keys. You are also going to retrieve the values by iterating over the map rather than via indexing by key. This all defeats the purpose of even having keys, so why even use a map at all and not just use a list in the first place?